# Intel HDA audio not working

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio

Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Kubuntu 23.04 on an ASUS laptop TP510UQ kernel 6.2.0-24.  No sound from speakers until headphones are plugged in, then no sound from headphones but sound from speakers. How to fix?